# SUM (row_count) FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats is very slow

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

I'm performance tuning our application and have found one of our bottlenecks is a previous performance tuning.

To get the count of rows in all our tables we are using

```
SELECT SUM (row_count)
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE object_id=OBJECT_ID('{0}')
AND (index_id=0 or index_id=1);
```

with comments to show that it's because count(*) is too slow.  However this is currently taking 500ms to return.  Now it's about 500ms for every table regardless off size so for comparison with count(*) 50 row table takes 0ms, 2M row table takes 200ms and 50M row table takes 900ms.

The 50M row table is an exception really almost of the other tables are in the thousands so I'm tempted to go for count(*)

my question is: Is the dm_db_partition_stats select expected to be slow but returns regardless of how big the table is? Or is this not expected and I can do something about it.

Comment: How many times are you running this query for 700ms to be worth botherign about?

Comment: Mine is pretty fast and my total is 1,1 bil rows. Cant see how it can be slow. Mine return with 0 secs

Comment: It shouldn't be taking 500ms+. You might [try updating system table stats](http://www.dbdelta.com/sql-server-system-table-statistics-update/).

Comment: @DanGuzman I've tried updating the system table stats, no discernible improvement. Any other ideas?

Comment: @plaidDK yes the performance is comparatively great for big tables it just seems to be the same speed no mater what the table size

Comment: @CaiusJard probably too many times but we're inheriting and overriding a component that seems to be count happy, half seconds add up really fast.